# How to add sidebar unscrolable

Tags: jquery

How to create sidebar unscrolabe like lifehacker dot com? using CSS3 or jQuery or what?

I have searching in jquery plugins database and found nothing

Please Help,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with `position: fixed`:

```
.sidebar 
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHB7N/).